# node specific google analytics tags in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, analytics

I need to put this kind of tags (floodlight/doubleclick - Google Analytics) in some nodes in my Drupal site -each code snippet/GA tag is specific and different-. How can I put this specific tags in specific nodes? -near the  tag if possible?- 
blocks? or there's a module that could help in this case?

Thanks for any help, this is an emergency!

```
<!--
Inicio de la etiqueta Floodlight de DoubleClick: No elimine el
nombre de actividad de esta etiqueta: Tag 001
URL de la página Web en la que se espera que se inserte la etiqueta: 
Esta etiqueta se debe insertar entre las etiquetas <body> y </body>, tan cerca como sea posible 
de la etiqueta de apertura.
Fecha de creación: 09/06/2011
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<iframe src="http://fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=33000080;
type=tagss090;        cat=tag00425;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" 
style="display:none"></iframe>');
</script>
<noscript>
<iframe src="http://fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=33000080;type=tagss090;cat=tag00425; 
ord=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>
</noscript>
<!-- Fin de la etiqueta Floodlight de DoubleClick: No eliminar -->
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I've typically done tracking codes like that in the past was to add the code to a block in Drupal and use the block visibility settings to specify which nodes to load the block on.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't help with the OP's SEO "emergency", but this module was reviewed and published as full project to Drupal.org a few months ago and might help someone else who ends up on this post after searching Google for drupal + doubleclick + floodlight.

https://www.drupal.org/project/doubleclick_floodlight